# What is the exact historic meaning of gaming?

Tags: vocabulary, archaicisms

Did a few google searches on this, but not to my surprise, only results about video gaming come up.

In Hamlet, Reynaldo says: "As **gaming**, my lord." 
to which Polonius replies "Ay, or drinking, fencing, swearing, Quarreling, drabbing—you may go so far"

or to describe Germans, British lexicographer Sir William Smith writes: “Their men found their chief delight in the perils and excitement of war. In peace they passed their lives in listless indolence, only varied by deep **gaming** and excessive drinking.”

I'm guessing it means something along the lines of having fun, but is there a more specific definition that anyone knows?

Comment: It means gambling—playing games of chance. "Deep" gaming would be high-stakes gambling.

Answer (score 1):

The OED and every other source I know of, has the the Old English *gamen* as the ancestor word.
The original meaning of "amusement" or "fun" hasn't changed much, but, the applications of the word have certainly multiplied.

"Game" might be what is hunted for sport, or a memory device that contains the information needed to play a video "game".

There are many uses for "game", and "gaming" as a act of participating in a game has several current uses also. A very popular use is computer "gaming".

But, as to *Hamlet*, the context of

> "As gaming, my lord." to which Polonius replies "Ay, or drinking, fencing, swearing, Quarreling, drabbing—you may go so far"

more than suggests games of skill, amusement or fun, probably with wagers.
Younger folks would think computers when "gaming" is mentioned, some older folks will think of gambling, or playing the games involved with gambling.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wiktionary's etymology section](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/game), it means having fun, hunting, shooting, fishing etc. It comes from Middle English game, gamen, gammen, from Old English gamen ‎(“sport, joy, mirth, pastime, game, amusement, pleasure”).

Hence a game bird is one which is shot for amusement, a game larder is a place where such birds are hung and stored.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context. "Game" can refer to animals hunted for meat.  But I don't think that "gaming" is ever used to mean hunting.  In modern times, "gaming" can mean "to play a game like a video game, or a board game".  A person can "game the system" which means exploiting loopholes for their own advantage.

In your two quotes, based on the approximate era and context, "gaming" means gambling for money.